# How to determine row height in bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-2

I will preface by saying that I have extremely basic knowledge of html and css. I do not know anything really about jquery or bootstrap, even though my website makes use of both of those (I'm making changes to a free template I'd found online) :S. So I apologize in advance for my ignorance.

And so, even though I've searched for a solution, I'm not able to understand the other posts that may address the problem I'm experiencing.

**The problem:**
What's happening is that bootstrap (I think) seems to have pre-determined (through CSS) the line-height for the rows and my items are going beyond that parameter because of the amount of text and the font-size. And because of that, what's happening is that the items in the row below are being shifted over (see Figure 1).

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jRhv.jpg)

I don't want the second column to be shifted to the right. I want it to be shifted down so that the left 'wall' of the first items in each row are flush with one another (see Figure 2).

[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yHNs.jpg)

Normally, I would just adjust the stylesheet but I've tried adding a line-height to the .row class and that hasn't helped and I don't understand a lot of the bootstrap.min file that came with the template.

I don't think I can provide attachments here and I'm not even sure which portion of the code is the 'problem' so I can't paste that. The template I am using is Andia, in case that helps.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The Vivid Stroke</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/prettyPhoto/css/prettyPhoto.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/flexslider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Favicon and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="navbar">
                    <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </a>
                        <h1>
                            <a class="brand" href="index.html">The Vivid Stroke</a>
                        </h1>
                        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="index.html"><i class="icon-home"></i><br />Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="current-page">
                                    <a href="portfolio.html"><i class="icon-camera"></i><br />Portfolio</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-comments"></i><br />Blog</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="services.html"><i class="icon-tasks"></i><br />Services</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="about.html"><i class="icon-user"></i><br />About</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="contact.html"><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i><br />Contact</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Page Title -->
    <div class="page-title">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <i class="icon-camera page-title-icon"></i>
                    <h2>Portfolio /</h2>
                    <p>Here is some of my work</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Portfolio -->
    <div class="portfolio portfolio-page container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="portfolio-navigator span12">
                <h4 class="filter-portfolio">
                    <a class="all" id="active-imgs" href="#">All</a> /
                    <a class="corporate" id="a" href="#">Corporate</a> /
                    <a class="abstract" id="b" href="#">Abstract</a> /
                    <a class="photorealism" id="c" href="#">Photorealism</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
            <ul class="portfolio-img">
                <li data-id="p-1" data-type="corporate" class="span3">
                    <div class="work">
                        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/work1.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work1.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <h4>May and Associates Law</h4>
                        <p>This painting hangs in the lobby of May and Associates law offices where dozens of people view the mosaic/abstract hybrid everyday.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-id="p-2" data-type="corporate" class="span3">
                    <div class="work">
                        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/work2.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work2.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <h4>Purple Market</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-id="p-3" data-type="corporate" class="span3">
                    <div class="work">
                        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/work3.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work3.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <h4>Wheels on a Frame</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-id="p-4" data-type="abstract" class="span3">
                    <div class="work">
                        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/work4.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work4.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <h4>Exploding Sky</h4>
                        <p>When the isotope filters are activated, it throws the rows off because of the height of previous items</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-id="p-5" data-type="photorealism" class="span3">
                    <div class="work">
                        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/work5.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work5.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <h4>Consectetur Logo</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-id="p-6" data-type="corporate" class="span3">
                    <div class="work">
                        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/work6.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work6.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <h4>Adipisicing Print</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-id="p-7" data-type="corporate" class="span3">
                    <div class="work">
                        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/work7.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work7.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <h4>Elit Website</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-id="p-8" data-type="print-design" class="span3">
                    <div class="work">
                        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/work8.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work8.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <h4>Sed Do Prints</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-id="p-9" data-type="web-design" class="span3">
                    <div class="work">
                        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/work9.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work9.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <h4>Eiusmod Website</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-id="p-10" data-type="logo-design" class="span3">
                    <div class="work">
                        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/work10.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work10.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <h4>Tempor Logo</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-id="p-11" data-type="web-design" class="span3">
                    <div class="work">
                        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/work11.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work11.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <h4>Incididunt Website</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-id="p-12" data-type="print-design" class="span3">
                    <div class="work">
                        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/work12.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work12.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <h4>Ut Labore Print</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

    </div>


    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="widget span3">
                    <h4>About Us</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.</p>
                    <p><a href="">Read more...</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="widget span3">
                    <h4>Latest Tweets</h4>
                    <div class="show-tweets"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="widget span3">
                    <h4>Flickr Photos</h4>
                    <ul class="flickr-feed"></ul>
                </div>
                <div class="widget span3">
                    <h4>Contact Us</h4>
                    <p><i class="icon-map-marker"></i> Address: Via Principe Amedeo 9, 10100, Torino, TO, Italy</p>
                    <p><i class="icon-phone"></i> Phone: 0039 333 12 68 347</p>
                    <p><i class="icon-user"></i> Skype: Andia_Agency</p>
                    <p><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i> Email: <a href="">contact@andia.co.uk</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-border"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="copyright span4">
                    <p>Copyright 2012 Andia - All rights reserved. Template by <a href="http://azmind.com">Azmind</a>.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="social span8">
                    <a class="facebook" href=""></a>
                    <a class="dribbble" href=""></a>
                    <a class="twitter" href=""></a>
                    <a class="pinterest" href=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.tweet.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jflickrfeed.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.ui.map.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.quicksand.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/prettyPhoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: The link for the Andia template is:
http://azmind.com/2012/12/28/free-html-template-andia-responsive-agency-portfolio-template-twitter-bootstrap/

Comment: You might want to post some code to simplify things. --- A row has the height of your largest column, or the height of the highest stacked columns. Obviously if all columns are the same height they will align properly. You either want to start a new row every 2 or 4 items or make sure your columns are the same height to prevent them from interfering with each other.

Comment: Do you want all the boxes to scale to the height of the largest one?

Comment: Can you not simply add style="height : SOME HEIGHT; overflow scroll | hidden;" in your wrapper of image and content? or only to your content holder of single item?

Answer (score 0):

Try This. Put as much text you want.

```
<div class="work-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 work-title wow fadeIn animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeIn;">
                <h2>Our Latest Work</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        // First Row.
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="work wow fadeInUp animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
                    <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work1.jpg" alt="Lorem Website" data-at2x="assets/img/portfolio/work1.jpg">
                    <h3>Lorem Website</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor...</p>
                    <div class="work-bottom">
                        <a class="big-link-2 view-work" href="assets/img/portfolio/work1.jpg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                        <a class="big-link-2" href="portfolio.html"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="work wow fadeInDown animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInDown;">
                    <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work2.jpg" alt="Ipsum Logo" data-at2x="assets/img/portfolio/work2.jpg">
                    <h3>Ipsum Logo</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor...</p>
                    <div class="work-bottom">
                        <a class="big-link-2 view-work" href="assets/img/portfolio/work2.jpg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                        <a class="big-link-2" href="portfolio.html"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="work wow fadeInUp animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
                    <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work3.jpg" alt="Dolor Prints" data-at2x="assets/img/portfolio/work3.jpg">
                    <h3>Dolor Prints</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor...</p>
                    <div class="work-bottom">
                        <a class="big-link-2 view-work" href="assets/img/portfolio/work3.jpg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                        <a class="big-link-2" href="portfolio.html"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="work wow fadeInDown animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInDown;">
                    <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work4.jpg" alt="Sit Amet Website" data-at2x="assets/img/portfolio/work4.jpg">
                    <h3>Sit Amet Website</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor...</p>
                    <div class="work-bottom">
                        <a class="big-link-2 view-work" href="assets/img/portfolio/work4.jpg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                        <a class="big-link-2" href="portfolio.html"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        // Second Row Here
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="work wow fadeInUp animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
                    <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work1.jpg" alt="Lorem Website" data-at2x="assets/img/portfolio/work1.jpg">
                    <h3>Lorem Website</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor...</p>
                    <div class="work-bottom">
                        <a class="big-link-2 view-work" href="assets/img/portfolio/work1.jpg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                        <a class="big-link-2" href="portfolio.html"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="work wow fadeInDown animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInDown;">
                    <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work2.jpg" alt="Ipsum Logo" data-at2x="assets/img/portfolio/work2.jpg">
                    <h3>Ipsum Logo</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor...</p>
                    <div class="work-bottom">
                        <a class="big-link-2 view-work" href="assets/img/portfolio/work2.jpg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                        <a class="big-link-2" href="portfolio.html"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="work wow fadeInUp animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
                    <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work3.jpg" alt="Dolor Prints" data-at2x="assets/img/portfolio/work3.jpg">
                    <h3>Dolor Prints</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor...</p>
                    <div class="work-bottom">
                        <a class="big-link-2 view-work" href="assets/img/portfolio/work3.jpg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                        <a class="big-link-2" href="portfolio.html"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="work wow fadeInDown animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInDown;">
                    <img src="assets/img/portfolio/work4.jpg" alt="Sit Amet Website" data-at2x="assets/img/portfolio/work4.jpg">
                    <h3>Sit Amet Website</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor...</p>
                    <div class="work-bottom">
                        <a class="big-link-2 view-work" href="assets/img/portfolio/work4.jpg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                        <a class="big-link-2" href="portfolio.html"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What should I do with this code? If I'm supposed to implement it into my page, I don't understand how (as in which parts and what should it replace)...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use "row row-eq-height" classes.

Try to use `<div class="row row-eq-height"></div>` instead of `<div class="row"></div>`

And add this CSS property to your custom CSS

```
.row-eq-height{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this but it did not work. It extended the height of each item to match the tallest one in the row, but the second and third rows are still not flush with the left side of the page.

Comment: although, which stylesheet should I have put these properties into? 
I have the general styles.css
But I also have 
bootstrap.min.css
and
bootstrap.css

The last two are where the .row class are defined.

Comment: You have to use this code in your Style.css file. Could you give the link to your site with this issue?

Comment: Okay, I placed it into the style.css file and changed the div names in the html to <div class="row row-eq-height"> but that still didn't help.

I don't have the site up yet since I'm still developing. This is the link to the template:

http://azmind.com/demo/andia-agency/portfolio.html

So, you'll notice that it works fine there (even when you click on the isotope filters). The problem arises as soon as you add an extra line to any of the descriptions of the items (e.g. Lorem Website) and that's when the row below shifts.

Comment: I noticed that your theme's Bootstrap lacks classic Bootstrap grid's components (such as col-sm-3). So your grid should have such a structure `<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="col-sm-3"> </div></div></div>` In your case you should structure your grid like this content [link](http://www.bootply.com/JNJIeir7NM) . This should help.

Comment: No, unfortunately that didn't work. It's now justifying the second row to the right which only has one item before moving onto the third row. BTW, Is there a css component that I need to add for the col-sm-12 and col-sm-3 divs?

Just to clarify, I want a row of 4 items across. e.g. (template) "lorem website", "ipsum logo", "dolor prints", and "sit amet website" in one row and then another four under it and so on and so on.

The problem is the fact that it's indenting the second row.

I can sort of solve the problem by creating new row divs after every 4 items....

Comment: ... But the same problem emerges once the isotope filters are used (where the fifth item is indented on the second row).

Again, I'm swimming in the deep end here and am not an expert but It seems as though there is a maximum height assigned to the row somewhere, I just don't know where that is designated and so I can't fix it.

Comment: Ok, let's think. Can you post here the full code of your homepage file?

Comment: Sure, I've added it to the original question because of the character limit for the comments.
Also it's the portfolio file that I'm having trouble with which I've pasted above (if you still want the homepage/index file, please let me know)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not letting me paste the entire code because it is regestering the following as improperly formatted code:

            "<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
  
<div class="col-xs-3">"

That is right above " <ul class="portfolio-img">" in the code above

Also, because I had to remove that, i also had to remove the three closing divs just before the footer begins.

Comment: Ok, just put your code here [link](http://www.bootply.com/new) and press "Save" (Header top left part) ands share the resulting link here.

Comment: Done, here's the link:
http://www.bootply.com/gooHoeu8cJ

I added the css code from the styles.css file into the CSS section but I left the javascript in the HTML section. I hope that's okay.

Comment: I've removed the isotope filters and just gone with regular html links for now. If someone does have a solution for this though, it would be greatly appreciated.